# PHP framework for building e-commerce site?

Tags: php, frameworks, e-commerce

What web application framework based on php would be recommended to build an ecommerce site in?

Are there an e-commerce specific frameworks that include payment processing, user accounts, etc?

Thanks
B

Comment: thanks for all the replies- i'm looking mostly for a framework, so not a full blown ecommerce package. my experience has been that it is a nightmare to customize the frontend of most of these packages and you are limited in the way they do the checkout, or the way they present products, etc.

Comment: Would you like to try an AvoRed an Laravel E commerce. Laravel is one of the best framework in PHP so if you like give it a try. https://github.com/avored/laravel-ecommerce

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OpenCart is designed feature rich, easy to use, search engine friendly and with a visually appealing interface.

- Unlimited Categories
- Unlimited Products
- Unlimited Manufacturers
- Multi Currency
- Multi Language
- Product Reviews
- Product Ratings
- Open Source
- Free Documentation
- Templatable
- Automatic Image Resize
- 20+ Payment Gateways
- 8+ Shipping Methods

Demo:

- [Frontend](http://demo.opencart.com/)
- [Admin](http://demo.opencart.com/admin/) (demo / demo)

Download:

You can download from the [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) Website or [Directly (V1.4.9.1)](http://opencart.googlecode.com/files/opencart_v1.4.9.1.zip)

My thoughts:

With systems like Magento and osCommerce, there very bulky and poorly coded, OpenCart is a MVC Style framework, so if you have ever used codeigniter you would know half the system already.

The system does not take up heavy resources unlike some frameworks, it has a robust admin interface that shows you graphical statistics of your sales and helps you forcast sales, simple and logical payment api systems which allow you to add more payment systems with just drag and dropping of files.

Comment: Opencart has one of the most attractive front-ends out of the box, but suffers from a lot of bad code.

Comment: I don't think it suffers from that much bad code, I admit there's a few issues with it, but its so lightweight it compensates the performance, For a startup shop what would you go for? Megento Vs OpenCart ?

Comment: Magento system is not coded poorly, they are very complex and large

Comment: I am a large fan of the KISS Concept http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement.  After analysis I found that CodeIgniter Framework suits this requirement well.  It has a cart class which helps to develop a ecommerce application quicker and cleaner.  Also there is a Shopping Cart application based on CodeIgniter called GoCart (gocartdv.com).  This is a very simple shopping cart which has only those minimal feature required for a shopping cart.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal** is a multi-site framework and **Ubercart** is its ultimate e-commerce addon.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but hopefully useful to others. Look into [www.egg-basket.com](http://www.egg-basket.com). It's a million times easier to use than the likes of Magento and really easy to build up from.

Egg Basket differs in that it's a working store ready to be skinned up and populated with products, rather than being a tool intended to be used for setting a store up.

To me, this approach works because it means that to the end user, you've provided something bespoke with an admin panel that isn't full of developer tools, but all the hard work has still been done for you. It also results in an almost tiny footprint in comparison to Magento.

In terms of features, I don't think Egg Basket is amazing but it does have everything a basic store needs. It's an 'egg' :-)

Edit:
Just to add, this framework is much more reasonably priced these days and 1.4 was released today with a new plugins system. I genuinely don't know of an easier platform to work with!

Comment: Interesting link, but you could improve your answer by including more details about why it is, in your opinion, a better solution than the other ones in this page.

Comment: Hi Mathieu. Egg Basket differs in that it's a working store ready to be skinned up and populated with products, rather than being a tool intended to be used for setting a store up.

To me, this approach works because it means that to the end user, you've provided something bespoke with an admin panel that isn't full of developer tools, but all the hard work has still been done for you. It also results in an almost tiny footprint in comparison to Magento.

In terms of features, I don't think Egg Basket is amazing but it does have everything a basic store needs. It's an 'egg' :-).

Comment: Thanks for answering. However you can edit your answer to add this information, it will be very useful for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu - I've copied this in to my main post.

Comment: where's the source code though ? I can't seem to find it anywhere on their website ?, I don't mean the tarball, but the version control repo

Comment: There's a download page on the website for the source code, but it hasn't been updated for over a year now unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it personally but [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) probably has the best reputation among the PHP-based eCommerce frameworks.

Comment: Magento is not a framework, but it's built on top of the zend framework. It's probably the best way to go if you want a free eCommerce system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Magento too, it is based on Zend framework, which is robust, and is still fully supported.

The documentation is not easy to find, but it is very easy to add basic feature.

Here is a list of Magento [tutorials](http://onerutter.com/web/helpful-magento-tutorials-from-the-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a framework CodeIgniter has a nice cart class built in, and is very well documented. If you don't want to start from scratch I recommend CS-Cart (small site) or Magento (huge site).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.heroframework.com/ This is built on the top of the CodeIgniter framework and this is built on the top of the Zend Framework http://www.enlight.de/

Answer (score 0):

[ZenMagick](http://zenmagick.org/) has really high quality code...it's a full system but the API is flexible enough that you could completely rewrite the interface if you wanted.

It also makes use of several Symfony 2 bundles, so if you're familiar with Symfony that could be a plus.

Comment: Does this package include English? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: It looks like it hasn't been updated since Aug. 2013, and they didn't renew the zenmagick.org domain name. But for my project, I ended up going with a different system (as the underlying basis of a custom system) and it worked quite well: https://en.shopware.com. In the previous system most of the docs were available in English except for a few...it looks like all the docs might be available in English in the latest version.

Comment: I haven't used Shopware except for that one custom project where I was only using the underlying code...but the quality of the code and use of modern open-source projects like Doctrine is a plus either way. It will probably need a few tweaks though; for example, Washington, DC is missing from the list of states for the U.S.

Comment: Washington, DC isn't technically a state ;) But thanks for the reply. I know it's been a very long time and I really appreciate it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Haha, true, but if someone lives in DC but is forced to pick another state just to be able to enter their address, that's not good... :)